# Simple submit button with ember.js

Tags: ember.js, form-submit

I am brand new to ember and just want to show a submit button prototype. There does not appear to be a submit action so I am using the following script in my app.js file:

```
 Ember.ObjectController.extend({
 actions: {
 submit: function() {
 this.get('content').save(); 
 }
```

HTML as follows:

```
<form {{action "submit" on="submit"}}>
        {{input value=""}}  <button type="submit" id="button">nubmit name</button>
</form>
```

However in my javascript console I am getting the following error:

```
 Error: Nothing handled the action 'submit'. If you did handle the action, this error can be caused by returning true from an action handler in a controller, causing the action to bubble.
  return params[this.name];
```

Is this because my action is assigned to the form as opposed to the button itself?

Answer (score 0):

the actions should be handled in the route or controller of the particular view.

```
App.FooRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  actions:{
    submit: function(){}
  }
});


App.FooController = Em.Controller.extend({
  actions:{
    submit: function(){}
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, why does it have to be in the Route? I am still getting the same error.

Comment: or controller, the pattern is controller, route, then up the router's tree. http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/

Comment: Will you please show an example of how you're using it on emberjs.jsbin.com

Comment: sorry, I missed above that you were extending an object controller, my mind saw Object.  Will you show the router, the controller name, the route associated etc?

Comment: Sorry Kingpin,  I had to find an alternative option to ember as I did not have enough time to figure out why it was so complicated to set-up a simple submit button.